# How to deserialize object with nested query in a simply way

Tags: json, object, deserialize, nested

I have a JSON of object with nested query and I do not want to use JSON.deserializeUntyped and map values manually.

Is there any easy way to do it?

For example: Sobject object = (Sobject) JSON.deserialize(file, Sobject.class);

that is returning me the main object not nested ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It does not show up on the logs when you check it. However, the reality is, if you try to reach to child object by following script, it does return you the record array for the child object.

```
workItem.getSObjects('childRelationShipNameForStandardObject') or 
workItem.getSObjects('childRelationShipNameForCustomObject__r')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON needs to include the proper structure. For example, this will deserialize fine:

```
{
 "attributes":{
  "type":"Account"
 },
 "Name":"Demo",
 "Contacts":{
  "done":true,
  "size":1,
  "records":[
   {
    "attributes": {
     "type":"Contact"
    },
    "FirstName":"John",
    "LastName":"Doe"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

As long as you fully construct the JSON correctly, it will work as you expect. If you're having trouble getting it just right, consider running a query and serializing it to a JSON string to see how it should appear.

Comment: Yes, I did a query and serialised it. But when you deserialise it, you see only main object, as in previous answer by using xxx.getSObjects('childRelationShipNameForCustomObject__r'), it works

Comment: @FerhatÖzsavran Ah yes, that's a limitation of System.debug, it's still there. That's typically why people use JSON.serialize before debugging when queries are involved.